# CXF wsdl2java not resolving catalog

Tags: java, xml, xsd, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm using the wsdl2java tool with the cxf-codegen-plugin for maven in an **offline** scenario.
I have a jar *Types.jar* including common XML Schemata which are translated to java classes using the jaxb2-maven-plugin. I'm using an OASIS xml catalog to refer to local copies of common schemata like e.g. xmldsig-core-schema.xsd. This works so far.

I also have a *WebService.jar* which consists of a wsdl and an accompaning xsd, which imports Schemata from *Types.jar*.

When running the maven build, I get the following error:

```
    Loading FrontEnd jaxws ...
Loading DataBinding jaxb ...
wsdl2java -encoding UTF-8 -d C:\path\to\my\project\src\generated\java -b classpath:/xsd/Types.xjb -b classpath:/xsd/simpleBinding.schemalet -xjc-verbose -xjc-encoding -xjcUTF-8 -xjc-
catalog -xjcC:/path/to/my/catalog.cat -catalog C:/path/to/my/catalog.cat -p http://ws.myws.com/Test=com.myws.ws.test -verbose -wsdlLocation wsdl/MYWSDL.wsdl file:/C:/path/to/my/MYWSDL.wsdl
wsdl2java - Apache CXF 2.7.11

[DEBUG]
org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition file:/C:/path/to/my/MYWSDL.wsdl
_SOAP.wsdl: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/schema/xs:schema/xs:schema/schema): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'jar:file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/path/to/my/types.jar!/xsd/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd'.: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.w3.org
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:420)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:427)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:311)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:524)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition file:/C:/path/to/my/MYWSDL.wsdl_SOAP.wsdl: WSDLException (at /w
sdl:definitions/wsdl:types/schema/xs:schema/xs:schema/schema): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'jar:file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/path/to/my/types.jar!/xsd/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd'.: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.w3.org
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.parseWSDL(WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.build(WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:198)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/schema/xs:schema/xs:schema/schema): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'jar:file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/path/to/my/types.jar!/xsd/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd'.: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.w3.org
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2198)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:830)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:864)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:864)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:864)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:654)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(WSDLReaderImpl.java:610)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(WSDLReaderImpl.java:320)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2352)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2338)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:261)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:206)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.parseWSDL(WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:78)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.w3.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2188)
    ... 45 more
```

My catalog.cat looks like this:

```
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd" "classpath:/xsd/xml.xsd"
PUBLIC "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" "classpath:/xsd/xml.xsd"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XMLSchema 200102//EN" "classpath:/xsd/XMLSchema.dtd"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd" "classpath:/xsd/XMLSchema.dtd"
```

I tried cxf 2.7.6 and 2.7.11, I tried the XML catalog format, I even copied all the referenced Schemata to the *WebService.jar* without the *classpath:* expressions in the catalog, all with the same result and error message.

It seems the catalog Information is lost somewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please for plugin configuration from your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

(Yes, I'm two years late to the party, but) I believe this is bug [CXF-1505](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-1505) which is caused by [wsdl4j bug 34](https://sourceforge.net/p/wsdl4j/bugs/34/).

So:  those catalog.cat entries are probably fine (although you would also need one for datatypes.dtd, referenced from XMLSchema.dtd), but because of these bugs they end up being ignored.

One workaround, albeit rather grubby, is to modify your xsd/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd resource so that instead of referring to "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd" it just refers to "XMLSchema.dtd" in the same directory (and also put a copy of datatypes.dtd in that directory).